# Java Mail being blocked by gmail in some cases

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a running and working implementation of the Java Mail API. I am using the api to send out bulk email messages. On some occasions, the login gets blocked by google. So, I go to my gmail account and allow access to apps and set the security level to give access to apps that don't use what google calls "modern security". So, the google page tells me to try my program again. I try it again and it still won't let me log in. On some occasions when I have a login fail, I can go to the account, log in, and type in the recaptcha. This will allow me to log back in shortly after and send emails. However, the problem I am now experiencing does not show any recaptcha, nor does it say anything about any unknown apps that tried to access the account. It says nothing, and just wont let me log in to my account. I created two new accounts for testing and they worked fine. The account that I created that doesn't work only allowed me to send 17 emails before it blocked my service. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Gmail account setting page and `Enable` access of `Less secure apps`. Then try with Java Mail API. Hope it works for you.

[image]

Comment: This solution works for now, but at some point Google may switch GMail over to an OAuth-based workflow, at which point this option may no longer be available.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JavaMail with google auth is working fine, Check concurrently with Different app. If not post your code

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a free Gmail account, Google might think your bulk email is spam (duh).  If you're going to send bulk email, it may be time to pay someone for a business account that will let you do that.